# Image Pixel Analysis in React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, image-processing, expo

I'm trying to compare one image to another and depending on the similarity, I want to generate a score. The issue I'm running into is finding a way to compare the pixels of each of the images in a React Native and Expo supported way. I've checked out ResembleJS and a ton of other packages that can calculate percentage-wise how close an image is to another, but unfortunately these packages do not work in React Native. Is there any way I can implement this with React Native or can make a node file work effectively with the rest of my React Native project?